# Fetch in componentDidMount not getting response until after page reload

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to fetch data about an appointment from an express backend with a React appointment details component. My issue is that the response json I get is empty after I redirect to the component using `hashHistory.push("/appointment/" + this.state.id)`. After a page refresh or directly going to the url however, I get the correct json.

```
//Success.js
async componentDidMount() {
        try {
            const response = await fetch(`api/appointments/${this.props.params.id}`)
            if (!response.ok) {
                throw Error(response.statusText);
            }
            const json = await response.json()
            //console.log(json) displays an empty object first time component is loaded
            this.setState({ appointmentDetails: json })
        } catch(error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
    }
```

```
//react-router file
const Routes = (props) => (
  <Router {...props}>
    <Route path="/" component={App} />
    <Route path="/appointment" component={BookAppointment} />
    <Route path="/appointment/:id" component={Success} />
    <Route path="*" component={NotFound} />
  </Router>
);
```

```
//api.js
router.get('/appointments/:param', (req, res) => {
    const identification = new ObjectId(req.params.param)
    Appointment.find({_id: identification}, (err, appointment) => {
      if (err) console.log(err)
      else {
        res.json(appointment)
      }
    })
})
```

**UPDATE:**
The issue ended up being the fact that I didn't properly asynchronously post appointment details to the database before moving onto the fetch in componentDidMount in this component. Essentially I was trying to access an appointment that didn't exist yet in the database.

Comment: Put your fetch inside a useEffect() hook and it should work.

Comment: Was using useEffect originally and had the same behavior.

Comment: Can you open the Chrome browser network tab and see what's the API call being made when you refresh and when you navigate programmatically. I have doubt that something might be going different on both calls.

Comment: In addition, add a `console.log(this.props.params.id)` in `componentDidMount()` and make sure you are getting the id before calling the API.

Comment: @SanishJoseph console.log printed out the correct ID. I compared the two cURL requests in the network tab and they were almost identical. The request that gave the correct json response (after a page refresh) had an extra header If-None-Match

Comment: Can you try both requests on Postman? This is to narrow down the problem.

Comment: @SanishJoseph Both requests gave the same, correct response. I'm guessing this means this is just a React issue then.

Comment: I doubt the fetch API. Try passing an object to fetch calls like `fetch(\`api/appointments/${this.props.params.id}\`,{cache:"no-store"})`

Comment: @SanishJoseph Didn't change anything.

Comment: Hmm, that's a crazy issue. Try setting `headers: {    
    "content-type": "application/json"
  },` in the fetch api.

Comment: @SanishJoseph no change :(

Comment: I quit !! If there is no difference in the network tab of chrome that returns different results, I am out of ideas.

Comment: @SanishJoseph Thank you for your help regardless! It was helpful to verify that the fetch/network side is working. I think I have an idea of what may be causing it. Currently, I'm fetching data with the appointment ID I created on the previous page just before rendering this page. I think I may have screwed up the async await or something, so it's trying to fetch data that isn't in the database yet.

Answer (score 0):

`componentDidMount` is only called at first when the component is rendered.
When you update the url with another params, React doesn't recreate the component so you wont fetch as the `componentDidMount` is not called.

You need to observe the url param changes inside the component:

```
// Add this line to componentDidMount
this.unlisten = this.props.history.listen((location, action) => {
  // fetch here
});

// Add this line to componentWillUnmount
this.unlisten();
```

Comment: React won't call componentDidMount even though I'm going from the BookAppointment component to the Success component? If I uncomment the console.log in the componentDidMount, something does get printed--just the wrong thing... doesn't this mean that componentDidMount is being called?